# What is the best way to extend PhoneGap (cordova) for Windows 8

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-store-apps, winjs

Cordova/Phone Gap work differently on Windows 8.  There really isn't a native layer since the phonegap/cordova template uses WinJS directly.  What is the recommended way to extend cordova so that I can write a plugin?  Can someone post an example similar to their Echo example?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: Old question but I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone: http://www.risingj.com/archives/609